# Javascript touch events in an android webview

Tags: javascript, android, webview, touch-event

I have this [javascript code](http://pouzzler.free.fr/etagere/main.html) working correctly.
All it does is save a mousedown's coordinates, and modify the schematic on mouseup, depending on mousedown and mouseup coordinates.

Rather than reinvent the wheel, I am trying to use it in an android app, by loading it inside a webview.

The relevant changes are to change the mousedown and up listeners for :

```
            canvas.addEventListener("touchstart", saveDownCoords, false);
            canvas.addEventListener("touchend", modifySchematic, false);
```

and the function calculating the coordinates has been changed so :

```
function mouseCoords(e) {
  var cellSize = e.target.getAttribute("data-lib-shelves-cell-size");
  var cellRect = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
  return {
      //x : Math.floor((e.clientX - cellRect.left) / cellSize),
      //y : Math.floor((e.clientY - cellRect.top) / cellSize)
      x : Math.floor((e.touches[0].clientX - cellRect.left) / cellSize),
      y : Math.floor((e.touches[0].clientY - cellRect.top) / cellSize)
  };
}
```

Nothing works at all unless I touch several fingers. Then it does what the program did with the mouse, sometimes using the down from the first finger, and the up of the second finger; sometimes the down and up of the first finger, but only if a second finger was used, never when only one finger is.

I have not written a touch handler for the webview, nor for the activity inside which it resides.

Did anyone ever encounter such a behaviour?

Comment: I figured exactly what happened : everything works, apart that I need to put a second finger down. Then, upon release, everything works, taking only the first finger into account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem resided in the javascript logic.
One can't get a touchend's coordinates, but only the coordinates of the last touchmove before it.